# Is a question about the meaning of a certain passage from a book on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

I have a question about what a character in a certain book is talking about during a certain passage of said book, and I am wondering if that would be on-topic here.  If not, what site could i ask it on?

Comment: Come ask in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-usage). Now I'm curious.

Comment: Hi again :-) I think you should edit this question to be a bit more explicit. Since the character you're referring to is one who **speaks a special variety of English** (it's his idio-idio-idiosyncracy), that makes such a question more about "English language and usage" than if it was just any old normal-English-speaking character. cc @KitZ.Fox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the question. If you are asking about the meaning of a word or phrase in context and you can show that you have done some work to try to figure it out on your own (e.g., you've looked up the word or phrase in a dictionary and can explain what it means), it is probably on-topic.

On the other hand, if you are asking what the entire passage means in the context of the story, that would not be on-topic. I don't believe we have a site for that, but you could ask in chat.

Comment: It is an ambiguous passage in Charlotte's Web, and based on your guidelines I think it wouldn't be on topic here.  Thanks.